# iptables block INPUT port 80

Tags: iptables

My question is for general understanding and not for fixing an issue that I have.

I managed to run `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT` and block http requests. When I ran `curl http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js` I've got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to b.scorecardresearch.com port 80: Connection refused`

Then I deleted the OUTPUT rule and created an INPUT rule `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT`. I could then access `curl http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js` with no problems at all.

I understand why the outgoing request was not blocked but when I make an http request, doesn't the response return on the same port (80) and should be blocked by the INPUT REJECT of port 80?

Answer (score 2):

When you send an HTTP request to a server, unless otherwise specified in the URL, you use the default port for HTTP which is 80 (named `http`, symbolic forms are generally easier to remember). That's why this rule properly forbids connection attempts to a remote HTTP port:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport http -j REJECT
```

When the server is replying, it sends data from this port (http/80) to your machine. That means that the `iptables` rule should mention 80 as the source port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport http -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

No, on the client side there will be used a different port for the communication, so it is not a port 80 to port 80 connection.

You can get an overview with the command as follows. There you can see your local IP address and port and the related foreign IP address and port.

```
netstat -tn
```